# mailchimp signup form leads to 404

Tags: html, forms, mailchimp

I have a mailchip signup form in the [footer of my site](http://frshstudio.com/#optin). I've noticed recently that after trying to signup, the user is greeted with a 404:page not found error reading:

> MailChimp It seems the page you were looking for has disappeared We’ve
>   recorded this vanishing act and our team of chimp magicians will find
>   the missing link.

The form worked perfectly on my old site, I'm not quite sure why it's suddenly stopped- I didn't change anything but the styling.

Comment: Looks like mailchimp updated their signup form code or ask their support, seems like their server is missing a Redirect or something.

Answer (score 3):

When you create your MailChimp subscribe form, you have the option to specify your own Thank You page that users are sent to after they subscribe:

http://kb.mailchimp.com/article/can-i-design-and-host-my-own-thank-you-pages-instead-of-using-mailchimps/

Are you sure that MailChimp isn't trying to redirect your users back to a Thank You page of your own... that no longer exists on your end?

Regardless, I'd recommend going through the steps on that page to create a new subscribe form from scratch, specify the options including the Thank You page that you want to use, and place the new embed code in the footer of your website. That should fix whatever is currently broken.

Answer (score 0):

your question is broad,It may have multiple reasons:

**1:** Compare your old code and new code and see difference if any malicious code is written (includes other pages or script that leads to errors)

**2:** Check if the Signup page (abc.html etc) file is present on the server and not deleted/Renamed during deployment. Also check nested pages that are included as headers/ footers

**3:** Some times files are placed in the wrong directory. Make sure particular file is placed at the required location.

please specify what type of page is it and called from which source (JSP/simple html etc).